# How to set multiple return values to implicitly unwrapped variables direcly?

Tags: swift

I have a function that returns multiple values in this way:

```
func foo() -> (Int, Int) {
     // some code
     return (x, y)
}
```

Now in the class calling this function:

```
class myClass {
    private var myX : Int!
    private var myY : Int!

    func myFunc() {
        let ret = foo()
        myX = ret.0
        myY = ret.1
    }
}
```

If I set them like this

```
(myX, myY) = foo()
```

the compiler shows error

```
Cannot express tuple conversion '(Int, Int)' to '(Int?, Int?) ...
```

Is there a way to set `myX` & `myY` directly in this case?

Comment: This code compiles fine in Xcode 7.2 for me though needed  fix in Foo for undefined x & y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that's the message? When I try your code I get

```
Cannot express tuple conversion '(Int, Int)' to '(Int!, Int!)'
```

This makes sense, since myX and myY are implicitly unwrapped optionals. Changing foo to the following then works fine:

```
func foo() -> (Int!, Int!) {
     let x = 1
     let y = 2
     return (x, y)
}
```

Comment: Your message is right. I was playing with `Int?` so was my message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `didSet` on variable y. This assumes you want y to always equal x.

```
class myClass {
    private var myX : Int!
    private var myY : Int! {
                 didSet{
                     if myY != myX {
                         myX = myY
                     }
                 }
    }


    func myFunc() {
        let ret = foo()
        myY = ret.0
       //After you assign myY didSet is called and myX is will be set to the same.
    }
}
```